# Why is the phenomena of doping inversion assymetric under irradiation?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

According to the following plot,

[image]

taken from : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168900203018746

under irradiation, a doped-N semiconductor transforms into doped-P semiconductor,
but a doped-P semiconductor does not transform into doped-N semiconductor.

Why is the phenomena assymetric ?

Comment: maybe incident photons creating holes vs. creating free electrons?

Comment: maybe, maybe not : let's see if somebody "knows".

Comment: You are making lattice defects. So, what lattice defects result in generation of free carriers above the Fermi level? Right - none do. So, you make empty states in the valence band, making it p-type.

Comment: @Jon Custer : excellent. Thank you for sharing this.